# font size inherit control on mobile devices

Tags: css, sass

I am administrating a new site, where I have a problem with fontsizes. On the desktop version it is looking fine, but on mobile devices the text is way to big.

```
.blog {

        h2 {
            a {
                font-size:inherit;
                font-weight:inherit;
                color:inherit;
            }
        }
```

How can I control the font on mobile devices? Can I somehow add something like:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){

        .h1, h1 {
            font-size: 1.5em;
        }
        .h2, h2 {
        font-size: 26px;
        }
```

or is that the wrong way to do it?

With this solution the code would look like?:

```
.blog {

        h2 {
            a {
                font-size:inherit;
                font-weight:inherit;
                color:inherit;
            }


        @media screen and (max-width: 768px){

        .h1, h1 {
            font-size: 16px;
        }
        .h2, h2 {
        font-size: 12px;
        }
}
```

Comment: Have you added 
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> in your <head> tag ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a correct way to use it.

However here are some tips :

> Prefear using px over em

because the interpretation of em and ex depends on the OS. px will show the same size no matter what OS you are using.

> You can use relative values : **%**

% will make the font size proportional to his parent font size. This is very good for responsive design so you are going to change only one font size, the parent.

You can use [this link](http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/) for more information on what unit to use and why.

**EDIT :**

Your code needed some corrections : your CSS missed some `}`so I fixed it and was able to make your code work.

```
.blog {

    h2 {
        a {
            font-size:inherit;
            font-weight:inherit;
            color:inherit;
            }
        }


    @media screen and (max-width: 768px){

    .h1, h1 {
        font-size: 16px;
        }
    .h2, h2 {
        font-size: 12px;
        }
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/e3bzww63/1/)

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. I just updated my question with the code, I tried to use. I cannot make it work for some reason. Is there something I am doing wrong in the code?

Comment: I dont know much about SCSS so i simplified your code and made a JSfiddle for you. Try to adjust the width of the result. Let me know if it helps you. [JSfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/e3bzww63/)

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help again. Specially because I am really presured right now with time. It actually works when I do like you said: https://jsfiddle.net/t8yneyco/ . The only problem is now that the lineheight is double now. I tried to set it to normal, but that did not solve it.

Comment: @MadsKristensen I found the problem in your SCSS, edited my answer with the correct code and new SCSS

Comment: Ah yes good seen, I've missed that, sorry for that. When I run your code from the fiddle, the font on desktop also get smaller. I tried this : https://jsfiddle.net/f0n1pudk/ , and that is almost working, except that there are double spaces between the text now. Any idea?

Comment: Sorry sorry sorry, I bend my head. Your suggestion is working. I am using Blisk, and did not resize the window enought to get in full size. Thank you so much :)